# Adding __declspec(dllexport) to struct causes compilation error

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a struct in a DLL which, so far, has been used within that DLL, only.
I wanted to use the struct in another DLL, via pointer. So, I added `__declspec(dllexport)` to the struct definition. Simply adding that dll export statement is now causing the struct to fail to compile (not just the regular DLL export warnings). This is the first time that I've seen this behavior. I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I don't know what the underlying problem is.

What could be a reason that simply adding '__declspec(dllexport)' to a struct/class would make it fail compilation?

```
struct __declspec(dllexport) PipelineManager {
// ...
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>            mPathToName;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, vko::PipelineLayout>    mLayouts;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, vko::GraphicsPipeline>  mPipelines;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<GraphicsPipelineDef>> mDefs;
};
```

A chunk of the errors are below:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\xmemory0(820,1): error C2280:  'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\xmemory0(820,1): error C2280:         with
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\xmemory0(820,1): error C2280:         [
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\xmemory0(820,1): error C2280:             _Kty=std::string,
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\xmemory0(820,1): error C2280:             _Ty=std::unique_ptr<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,std::default_delete<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef>>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\xmemory0(820,1): error C2280:         ] (compiling source file Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer\GpuProgramManager.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133): message :  see declaration of 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133): message :         with
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133): message :         [
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133): message :             _Kty=std::string,
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133): message :             _Ty=std::unique_ptr<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,std::default_delete<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef>>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133): message :         ] (compiling source file Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer\GpuProgramManager.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :  'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)': function was implicitly deleted because a data member invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::unique_ptr<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :         with
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :         [
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :             _Kty=std::string,
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :             _Ty=std::unique_ptr<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,std::default_delete<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef>>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :         ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :         and
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :         [
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :             _Ty=ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27619\include\utility(133,5): message :         ] (compiling source file Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer\GpuProgramManager.cpp)

// ...

1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(67): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>::unordered_map(const std::unordered_map<_Kty,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>> &)' being compiled
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(67): message :         with
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(67): message :         [
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(67): message :             _Ty=ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(67): message :             _Kty=std::string
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(67): message :         ] (compiling source file Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer\GpuVM.cpp)
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(66): message :  see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>' being compiled
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(66): message :         with
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(66): message :         [
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(66): message :             _Ty=ngen::rendo::GraphicsPipelineDef,
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(66): message :             _Kty=std::string
1>Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer/PipelineManager.hpp(66): message :         ] (compiling source file Z:\NGEN\Source\Renderer\GpuVM.cpp)
```

Comment: Because the compiler needs to generate all the methods just in case somebody wants to call them. And then it runs into trouble generating the copy constructor because you have noncopyable objects in your `mDefs` member. Explicitly delete the copy constructor to make it uncallable.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That did the trick. Thanks!